# PUT json object to url returns Network error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a function to send requests to url

```
function json_object_todo(url, method, param_object, dataObj) {
    var json_obj;
    $.support.cors = true;
    try {
        var ajax_params = {
            type: method,
            url: url,
            async: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                json_obj = data;
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        }
        if (param_object)
            for (var propName in param_object) {
                ajax_params[propName] = param_object[propName];
            }
        if (dataObj) {
            ajax_params["data"] = JSON.stringify(dataObj);
        }
        var response = $.ajax(ajax_params);
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
    return json_obj;
}
```

I tried to use this function, for example

```
var newBinding = json_object_todo([serviceUrl, bindingRootUrl].join("/"), "PUT", { dataType: "json", contentType: "Application/json; charset=utf-8" }, { name: "New binding", "ref-id": "Taiwan-0001" });
```

I have got an error "Network error: ...", but I copied url and tried to make this request in Firefox RESTClient and "PUT" request working fine. See attached screenshot

http://i57.tinypic.com/10ykk5d.jpg

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check what you're sending to the server in developer tool when you're using json_object_todo

Comment: `async: false` is very bad thing. Moreover, do you understand that `var response` doesn't contain server answer?

Comment: artm, I only can see on tab Network in developer tool StatusCode, and Request/response headers.

Comment: Regent, yes I know that var response doesn't contain server answer, maybe it will be need for aborting or something else in future.

Comment: I already tried with the constants `$.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/bindings/",
        contentType: "Application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: '{ "name": "New binding", "ref-id": "Taiwan-0001" }',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });` and I'm still getting the error

Comment: In console I see the next error **XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/bindings/. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.**

Comment: Could it be due to the headers on the server?

Answer (score 0):

What I think, the service need contain header **Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept**, on **GET** and **DELETE** I don't send Content-Type header to service, therefore I didn't get an error. And on **PUT** and **POST** I have got, because I need to sent data and Content-Type header with them.